# What stresses should be considered to determine the effective stress and FOS?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque, statics, stress-strain, structural-beam

This question I tried to solve by considering the torsional shear and transverse shear and axial loading. But the answer is not clear. But the answers that I got by different trial and error method was 50ksi and around 100 ksi. And according to the question both are wrong. The Options given are 121.5ksi, 50.9ksi, 772.0ksi, 162.
I am confused and I tried for 3 days to get the answer to match.

Just for reference I had calculated the stress at D it is 772.0ksi. The hint given is to use the Distortion energy equation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The question hint demands the use of Distortion energy principle

Comment: Please show your calculations or your question might be closed. I expect to see the internal forces and moments at the base.

Comment: I wonder how would you account for the fillet radii in an analytical way?